# RemoteMediaClient fails for certain videos

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

In onSessionStarted() callback of SessionManagerListener I am doing,

```
final RemoteMediaClient rmc = getRmc();
rmc.addListener(mRemoteStatusUpdateListener);

//Video url
MediaInfo.Builder bulider = new MediaInfo.Builder(url);
MediaMetadata md = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_TV_SHOW);

//Title for notification
String title = (episodeName + " " + seriesName).trim();
md.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, title.isEmpty() ? getString(R.string.app_name) : title);

//Images for notification
String imagePath = getThumbnailImage();
if (imagePath != null) {
    md.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse(imagePath)));
    md.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse(imagePath)));
}

//Adding licence
JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
try {
    j.put("widevine_key", mStreamCustomFromServer);
    j.put("playready_key", mStreamCustomFromServer);

    j.put(Constants.PlayListConst.EPISODE_NAME, episodeName);
    j.put(Constants.PlayListConst.SERIES_NAME, seriesName);

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

MediaInfo.Builder mi =
        bulider.setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
                .setContentType("video/mp4")
                .setMetadata(md)
                .setCustomData(j);

//We send a custom message to cast server to clear the player state (custom message sending part is not put here) and then load media as follows

rmc.load(mi, true, seekTo).setResultCallback(new ResultCallbacks<RemoteMediaClient.MediaChannelResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NonNull RemoteMediaClient.MediaChannelResult mediaChannelResult) {

            //Handling success
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Status status) {

            //Handling failure

        }
    });
```

The rmc.load(mi, true, seekTo) gives me no callbacks for some videos. And no progress update callbacks after this. But video will be playing in Chromecast.
In onLoad() method of myplayer.js file, I am doing,

```
myPlayer.CastPlayer.prototype.onLoad_ = function(event) {
    var info=new cast.receiver.MediaManager.LoadInfo((event.data),event.senderId);
    var initialSeek = info.message.currentTime;
    var stream = {
        startTime: initialSeek,
        url: info.message.media.contentId,
        protData: {
            'com.widevine.alpha': {
                laURL: 'http://widevine.licensekeyserver.com/',
                cdmData: info.message.media.customData.widevine_key,
            },
            'com.microsoft.playready': {
                laURL: 'http://sldrm.licensekeyserver.com/core/rightsmanager.asmx',
                cdmData: info.message.media.customData.playready_key,
            }
        }
    };

    // Initialize player.
    videoKeyOs = new MediaPlayer();
    videoKeyOs.init(videoHtml);
    videoKeyOs.setAutoPlay(info.message.autoplay);
    videoKeyOs.setConfig({
        '// Debug.level': 'The level for output debug messages (0=none, 1=error, 2=warn, 3=info, 4=debug)',
        'Debug.level': 1
    });
}
```

The getRmc() method,

```
private RemoteMediaClient getRmc() {
    CastSession cs = getCurrentSession();
    if (cs != null) {
        return cs.getRemoteMediaClient();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The getCurrentSession() method,

```
private CastSession getCurrentSession() {
    SessionManager sm;
    if (mCastContext != null && ((sm = mCastContext.getSessionManager()) != null)) {
        return sm.getCurrentCastSession();
    }
    return null;
}
```

If I add timeout to load method as,

```
rmc.load(mi, true, seekTo).setResultCallback(new ResultCallbacks<RemoteMediaClient.MediaChannelResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NonNull RemoteMediaClient.MediaChannelResult mediaChannelResult) {

            //Handling success
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Status status) {

            //Handling failure

        }
    }, 10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Then onFailure is called with status = [Status{statusCode=TIMEOUT, resolution=null}]

I wanted to know why is it failing for some videos. Someone please help me finding the solution.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you see on the receiver side in the console log when it fails?

Comment: I don't see any error logs. I see only the logs put by me and two warnings as follows.

1)It is recommended that a robustness level be specified. Not specifying the robustness level could result in unexpected behavior in the future, potentially including failure to play(from keyosplayer.js).
2)Mixed Content: The page at  (https://mywebsite.com/cctest/ccplayer.html) was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint  (http://widevine.licensekeyserver.com/). This content should also be served over HTTPS(from keyosplayer.js).

Comment: The reciever side behaviour is same as it is for working videos.
In sender side rmc.seek(current) works fine. 
The missings things are,
1)Video play state with video name in mini dialog which pops up when we tap on cast icon.
2)Notification view with play/pause control, which comes up when we go out of the app.
3)The volume control from device.